# How to get separate "global" module per instance?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible get individual "global" module for each instance?

```js
import MyModule from './index.js';

const first = new MyModule();
const second = new MyModule();

// PLEASE SEE EXAMPLE BELOW FOR LOGS

// expect to log for both:
// 1. "in entry: true"
// 2. "in init: true"

// but second module logs:
// 1. "in entry: false"
// 2. "in init: false"
```

Issue being here that both share `globals` and 1. instance changes property to `false`.

What are my options to have in individual `globals` module per instance?

**PS!** I have tens of thousands of lines of legacy code. Would be 100x better if I didn't need to change/remove/refactor `globals.js` contents nor these imports `import globals from './globals.js';`. Nevertheless, give all your ideas - I need to fix it, even if I need to change a lot.

---

#### Code for example above / minimal reproducible example

index.js

```js
import globals from './globals.js';
import init from './init.js';

export default function MyModule (conf) {
  console.log('in entry:', globals.state1);

  init();
}
```

globals.js

```js
export default {
  state1: true,
};
```

init.js

```js
import globals from './globals.js';

export default function init () {
  console.log('in init:', globals.state1);
  globals.entry1 = false;
}
```

Comment: Globals are global. How often do you do `import globals from './globals.js';`? And what do you want `init()` to do if each `MyModule` instance has individual "globals"? Especially what do you want it to do if it's not called from the `MyModule` constructor? Or is that the only place where it is used?

Comment: @Bergi It's imported hundreds of times in whole project. `globals.js` is basically "internal" module state (i.e each `MyModule` should have its own `globals` instance) that is easily sharable in hundreds of files (i.e 1 import away). Didn't have any issues with it until I needed to make 2 instances several years later.

Comment: But all these hundreds of modules that import the `globals` object, which of the two instances should they use now? And yes, you might have to bite the bullet and rewrite them all.

Comment: @Bergi All these modules are downstream from `MyModule` like `init`, so if `new MyModule()` is called, all downstream modules should use "individual" `globals`. Let's say I'm willing to rewrite, what would be the recommended "global state" solution here? (_vanilla JS_)

Comment: What do you mean by "downstream"? *Where* is `new MyModule()` called? How is the respective instance passed to the hundreds of modules?

Comment: Also, can you elaborate on "*I need to make 2 instances*"? Why exactly two? Can you just start the entire application twice?

Answer (score 0):

Since an object is passed by reference you need to create a copy each time you use `globals`.

A good way is to export a function like:

```
/* globals.js */
const globals = { // Maybe wrap the object in Object.freeze() to prevent side effects
    state1: true,
};

export default () => ({ ...globals });
```

You can then call the function to create a copy each time you need it.

```
/* init.js */
import getGlobals from './globals.js';

export default function init () {
  const globals = getGlobals();
  console.log('in init:', globals.state1);
  globals.entry1 = false;
}
```